# Ubuntu 18 login loop and can't open terminal

Tags: 18.04, virtual-console

I have upgraded my ubuntu 16 to 18 and after reboot I am stuck into login loop, found this [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

but I am also not able to open terminal from login screen, ctrl+alt+f* not working. Is there any other way I can open terminal ? like before login screen ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i suggest u to try this grub modification prior booting. this should boot u into a shell with hdd read/write permissions as root to do modifications: https://askubuntu.com/a/266608/669014 or https://askubuntu.com/a/24024/669014

Comment: How can I open grub with existing OS ?

Comment: sorry i dont understand your question? how to open grub menu is explained in the linksmi gave u: Hold Shift during boot to start GRUB menu

Comment: open grub?   Sorry I don't understand your comment.  Were you upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS or Ubuntu Core 18?  If Ubuntu 18.04 LTS have you tried editing your `grub` menu to remove `splash quiet` and add a `1` (or `single`) to boot into terminal mode (maintenance) to explore your system logs?  (*type `e` to edit your grub entry for that boot only*)

Comment: @guiverc yes I have upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, unfortunately holding shift not helping me to open grub menu, don't know what is causing the issue.

Comment: perhaps the keyboard is not beeing recognized during boot? an alternative would be to try different usb port or keyboard. old ps2 port should always work. actl i dont know of any other ways to get into the menu